# Do I need a manual Handshake and close event on Top of TCP?

Tags: ssl, tcp, network-programming

I am implementing a clipboard sync application I have already done packet definition for server discovery Request/Response, Clipboard sync Packet. But now I am confused about Handshake and disconnection. Probably My Application has UI like WIFI connect and disconnect options. A device can be a server or client but can't be both, If a client wants to connect to a server it initiates say TLS(on top of TCP) connection so the server knows there is a new client and asks for user permission to add this device as a client. Now what about Disconnection? if I disconnect the socket (By pressing the disconnect button) in the client is it detectable in the server? Or do I need to define a packet for Handshake and disconnection? What is the Good approach?

Comment: No. Just close the TLS socket.  The peer will get EOS when it reads to that, which tells it that its peer has disconnected, on which it should do the same. Nothing else required.

Comment: NB This has nothing to do with [tag:design-patterns], and not much to do with [tag:packet].

Comment: TLS already has a handshake on shutdown, the SSL shutdown alert. TCP has an additional handshake using FIN flags. No additional handshake is needed to detect  that the underlying socket was closed.

Answer (score 0):

Please take my answer with caution as it might be wrong, since i am a beginner.
I dont know about TLS but i know a bit about sockets.
When a socket closes, you usually receive a zero-byte at the other end.
So if you have something like

```
amountBytes = socket.receiveAsync(byteArray)
```

You could do:

```
If(amountBytes == 0){ yourDisconnectLogic }
```

At least this is how i handled sockets in c#.

Comment: You are welcome, hope you could solve your issue.